# Why is this arduino esp32 code not working?

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I am a beginner to programming

I am trying to program an ESP32 to show Bitcoin and Cardano price on an Adafruit SSD1306
128x64 OLED display based on the youtube video https://youtu.be/1Xas_UCOMvQ,
I want to show more than one crypto currency (bitcoin and cardano) but couldn't find a code for that so tried to do it myself by combining two codes from two guys (sources are mentioned below),
when I tried to run it is showing bitcoin price but for cardano it is showing **"null"**.

Can you tell me why it is not showing cardano price?

**code is given below**

```
//Bitcoin and Cardano Ticker
//Modified with codes from Michael Klements original version "https://www.the-diy-life.com/bitcoin-ticker-using-an-esp32-and-oled-display/"
("https://youtu.be/1Xas_UCOMvQ")and Vincent Rubens "https://github.com/xreactx/CryptoTicker/blob/main/CryptoTickerADA.ino"
//to include the Bitcoin logo and IO for the red and green indicator LEDs


#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>                                                 //Include the required libraries
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <NTPClient.h> 
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128                                                      //Define the OLED display width and height
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64
#define OLED_RESET     -1                                                     // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3C                                                   //I2C address for display
#define upLED 13
#define downLED 12
Adafruit_SSD1306 display (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);    //Create the display object

const char* ssid = "Your wifi name";                                            //Set your WiFi network name and password
const char* password = "your wifi password";

const int httpsPort = 443;                                                          //Bitcoin price API powered by CoinDesk - https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin
const String url = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json";
const String historyURL = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json";
const String cryptoCode = "BTC";
const String url1 = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=cardano&vs_currencies=usd&include_24hr_change=true";
                                                    //Cardano price API powered by CoinDesk - https://www.coingecko.com/


WiFiClient client;                                                            //Create a new WiFi client
HTTPClient http;

String formattedDate;                                                         //Create variables to store the date and time
String dayStamp;
String timeStamp;

const unsigned char bitcoinLogo [] PROGMEM =                                  // 'Bitcoin Logo', 128x64px
{
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xc0, 0x3f, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x00, 0x03, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x03, 0xe7, 0xc0, 0x07, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x03, 0xe7, 0xc0, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x80, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x80, 0x02, 0x3c, 0x40, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x03, 0xfe, 0x3c, 0x7c, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x03, 0xf0, 0x3f, 0x80, 0x60, 0x03, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x3f, 0xe0, 0x20, 0x01, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x70, 0x30, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x10, 0x30, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x10, 0x30, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x10, 0x30, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0xe0, 0x60, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x18, 0x3f, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x18, 0x3f, 0xe0, 0x18, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0xf8, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x1c, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x04, 0x0c, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x18, 0x30, 0x38, 0x0c, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x3f, 0xf0, 0x08, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x01, 0xe0, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x18, 0x01, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x03, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0xc0, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x03, 0xfe, 0x3c, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x80, 0x02, 0x3c, 0x40, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x80, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x02, 0x24, 0x40, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x03, 0xe7, 0xc0, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x03, 0xe7, 0xc0, 0x07, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x03, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xc0, 0x3f, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);                                                       //Start the serial monitor
  
  pinMode(upLED, OUTPUT);                                                     //Define the LED pin outputs
  pinMode(downLED, OUTPUT);

  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, SCREEN_ADDRESS))                   //Connect to the display
  {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for (;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }

  display.clearDisplay();                                                     //Clear the display
  display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);                                        //Set the text colour to white
  display.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitcoinLogo, 128, 64, WHITE);                             //Display bitmap from array
  display.display();
  delay(2000);

  display.clearDisplay();                                                     //Clear the display
  display.setTextSize(1);                                                     //Set display parameters
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  display.display();

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)                                        //Connect to the WiFi network
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  display.println("Connected to: ");                                           //Display message once connected
  display.print(ssid);
  display.display();
  delay(1500);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.display();
}


void loop() 
{
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");                                                       //Display url on Serial monitor for debugging
  Serial.println(url);

  http.begin(url);
  int httpCode = http.GET();                                                            //Get crypto price from API
  StaticJsonDocument<2000> doc;
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, http.getString());

  if (error)                                                                            //Display error message if unsuccessful
  {
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson Failed"));
    Serial.println(error.f_str());
    delay(2500);
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("HTTP Status Code: ");
  Serial.println(httpCode);

  String BTCUSDPrice = doc["bpi"]["USD"]["rate_float"].as<String>();                    //Store crypto price and update date in local variables
  String lastUpdated = doc["time"]["updated"].as<String>();
  http.end();

  Serial.print("Getting history...");
  StaticJsonDocument<2000> historyDoc;
  http.begin(historyURL);                                                               //Get historical crypto price from API
  int historyHttpCode = http.GET();
  DeserializationError historyError = deserializeJson(historyDoc, http.getString());

  if (historyError) {                                                                   //Display error message if unsuccessful
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson(History) failed"));
    Serial.println(historyError.f_str());
    delay(2500);
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("History HTTP Status Code: ");
  Serial.println(historyHttpCode);
  JsonObject bpi = historyDoc["bpi"].as<JsonObject>();
  double yesterdayPrice;
  for (JsonPair kv : bpi) {
    yesterdayPrice = kv.value().as<double>();                                           //Store yesterday's crypto price
  }

  Serial.print("BTCUSD Price: ");                                                       //Display current price on serial monitor
  Serial.println(BTCUSDPrice.toDouble());

  Serial.print("Yesterday's Price: ");                                                  //Display yesterday's price on serial monitor
  Serial.println(yesterdayPrice);
  
  bool isUp = BTCUSDPrice.toDouble() > yesterdayPrice;                                  //Check whether price has increased or decreased
  double percentChange;
  String dayChangeString = "24hr. Change: "; 
  if (isUp)                                                                             //If price has increased from yesterday
  {
    percentChange = ((BTCUSDPrice.toDouble() - yesterdayPrice) / yesterdayPrice) * 100;
    digitalWrite(upLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(downLED, LOW);
  } 
  else                                                                                  //If price has decreased from yesterday
  {
    percentChange = ((yesterdayPrice - BTCUSDPrice.toDouble()) / yesterdayPrice) * 100;
    dayChangeString = dayChangeString + "-";
    digitalWrite(downLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(upLED, LOW);
  }

  Serial.print("Percent Change: ");                                                     //Display the percentage change on the serial monitor
  Serial.println(percentChange);

  display.clearDisplay();                                                               //Clear the OLED display
  display.setTextSize(1);
  printCenter("BTC/USD", 0, 0);                                                         //Display the comparison header

  display.setTextSize(2);
  printCenter("$" + BTCUSDPrice, 0, 25);                                                //Display the current price
                                           
  display.setTextSize(1);                                                               //Display the change percentage
  dayChangeString = dayChangeString + percentChange + "%";
  printCenter(dayChangeString, 0, 55);
  display.display();                                                                    //Execute the new display
  display.clearDisplay();
  delay(5000);                                                                    //Execute the new display
 
 
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");                                              //Display url11 on Serial monitor for debugging
  Serial.println(url1);

  http.begin(url1);
  int httpCode1 = http.GET();                                                   //Get crypto price from API
  StaticJsonDocument<2000> doc1;
  DeserializationError error1 = deserializeJson(doc, http.getString());

  if (error)                                                                   //Display error message if unsuccessful
  {
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson Failed"));
    Serial.println(error1.f_str());
    delay(2500);
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("HTTP Status Code: ");
  Serial.println(httpCode1);
                                                   //Get crypto price from API                                              
  String ADAUSDPrice = doc1["cardano"]["usd"].as<String>();                     //Store crypto price and update date in local variables
  String percentChange1 = doc1["cardano"]["usd_24h_change"].as<String>();
  percentChange1.remove(4);                                                     //Adjust the decimal placement
  http.end();

  Serial.print("ADAUSD Price: ");                                              //Display current price on serial monitor

  bool isup1 = percentChange1 > "0";                                             //Check whether price has increased or decreased
  String dayChange1String = "24hr. Change: "; 
  if (isup1)                                                                    //If price has increased from yesterday
  {
    percentChange1 >= "0";
    digitalWrite(upLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(downLED, LOW);
  } 
  else                                                                         //If price has decreased from yesterday
  {
    percentChange1 < "0";
    digitalWrite(downLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(upLED, LOW);
  }

  Serial.print("Percent Change: ");                                            //Display the percentage change on the serial monitor
  Serial.println(percentChange1);

  display.clearDisplay();                                                      //Clear the OLED display
  display.setTextSize(1);
  printCenter("ADA/USD", 0, 0);                                                //Display the comparison header

  display.setTextSize(2);
  printCenter("$" + ADAUSDPrice, 0, 20);                                       //Display the current price

  display.setTextSize(1);                                                      //Display the change percentage
  dayChange1String = dayChange1String + percentChange1 + "%";
  printCenter(dayChange1String, 0, 55);
  display.display();                                                            //Execute the new display
  display.clearDisplay();
  delay(5000);
  
  http.end();                                                                  //End the WiFi connection
  esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(900000000);                                    //Sleep for 15 minutes
}

void printCenter(const String buf, int x, int y)                          //Function to centre the current price in the display width
{
  int16_t x1, y1;
  uint16_t w, h;
  display.getTextBounds(buf, x, y, &x1, &y1, &w, &h);                     //Calculate string width
  display.setCursor((x - w / 2) + (128 / 2), y);                          //Set cursor to print string in centre
  display.print(buf);                                                     //Display string
}
```

images are given below

[displaying "null" for cardano](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPcrw.jpg)

[for bitcoin its showing prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9hGS.jpg)

Comment: Are you seeing null on the display or on the serial monitor?

Comment: on the OLED display

Comment: What values of `doc1`, `doc1["cardano"]` and `doc1[cardano]["usd"]` do you get? (The last one is obviously null.) The URL seems to work (I tried in a browser).

Comment: I am new to programming, I don't know those values but I have attached the image of the output (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPcrw.jpg)

Comment: @mmixLinus "The last one is obviously null" how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

The error in the code is that you are parsing the wrong document, for the ADA case.  You are parsing the BTC doc instead of the ADA doc. In the following line, you should pass `doc1` as parameter, but you are passing the document that was received from the BTC url, `doc`.

Change

```
DeserializationError error1 = deserializeJson(doc, http.getString());
```

to

```
DeserializationError error1 = deserializeJson(doc1, http.getString());
```

Comment: Did that but its still showing null for ADA,Thanks for responding

Comment: @cathelena Are you perhaps getting an http error for the ADA case? Your error test is also wrong. `if (error)` should be `if (error1)` so your problem could be an https certificate problem, but it goes undetected.